# RethinkDB changefeed filtering using `now()`

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I was hoping to create a sort of 'time tigger' using RethinkDB changefeeds:

```
        return r.
            Table("Checks").
            Filter(r.Row.Field("ScheduledFor").Le(r.Now())).
            Changes(r.ChangesOpts{
                    IncludeInitial: true,
            }).Run(db)
```

However, while it picks up things that initially fulfill the `Filter` predicate, it does not appear to pick up records where `ScheduledFor` goes from being in the future to being in the past.

i.e. `r.Now()` appears to be evaluated upon being received by the server and never again.

Is there any way to make the `Now()` term dynamically evaluated? Or should I just do a table scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `r.now` always evaluates to the time the server received the query.  It's probably best to repeatedly do a table scan for any documents scheduled between the last table scan and the current time.